# Flutter native code to add DeepAR library to Agora video calls

Tags: flutter, agora.io, deepar

I need to implement AR filters in Video calls. And from research, this can be done by accessing the native layer of Android / iOS. I'm new to flutter Plugin development. can you suggest me pointers on how this can be achieved via the flutter SDK?

FYI: The DeepAR SDK can be integrated into the Agora Native SDK by pushing the frame to agora's pushExternalVideoFrame method.

Following a Github issue regarding the same: https://github.com/AgoraIO/Agora-Flutter-SDK/issues/615